# Exclude redundant rows containing different strings

Tags: r, duplicates

I would like to exclude rows from a data-frame which contain mirrored info. This is my input:

```
dfin <- 'info
      c1-10-20-c2-40-50
      c2-1-2-c4-20-25 
      c4-20-25-c2-1-2
      c2-40-50-c1-10-20'
dfin <- read.table(text=dfin, header=T)
```

In the above example you can see that rows `1` and `3`; `2` and `4` represent the same logic in a 'mirror'. In my context does not matter if I have `c1-10-20-c2-40-50` or `c2-40-50-c1-10-20`, thus I would like to filter one of this rows out (any of them). I don't have more than two redundant rows. Moreover, In my actual data-set these 'mirrored' rows are scattered and do not follow a pattern. My expected output:

```
dfout <- 'info
      c1-10-20-c2-40-50
      c2-1-2-c4-20-25'
dfout <- read.table(text=dfout, header=T)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can split the 'info' column by `-`, `sort` it, convert to a logical vector with `duplicated` which will be used for subsetting the rows.

```
dfN <- dfin[!duplicated(lapply(strsplit(as.character(dfin$info), "-"), sort)),, drop=FALSE]
all.equal(dfN, dfout, check.attributes=FALSE)
#[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach which does not keep the original order:

```
dfin <- 'info-info-info-info-info-info
      c1-10-20-c2-40-50
c2-1-2-c4-20-25 
c4-20-25-c2-1-2
c2-40-50-c1-10-20'
df <- read.table(text=dfin, header=T, sep = "-", strip.white = T)
dfout<-as.data.frame(unique(t(apply(df, 1, sort))))
```

I extended your column name to make it work.